# Why can't my Python code return the real part of a complex number?

Tags: python

I am having trouble extracting the real part of a complex number in my Python code. According to what I see, the program seems to recognize the whole complex number as real?

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

p = Symbol("p")
psol = solve((1+(0.596*p)-10)**2+(1+(0.556*p)-10)**2+(2+(0.556*p)-12)**2-1, p)
print("p = ", psol)

s = psol[0]
s_real = np.real(s)
s_imag = np.imag(s)
print("s = ", s)
print("s_real = ", s_real)
print("s_imag = ", s_imag)

p =  [16.3617836069885 - 0.632549329011281*I, 16.3617836069885 + 0.632549329011281*I]
s =  16.3617836069885 - 0.632549329011281*I
s_real =  16.3617836069885 - 0.632549329011281*I
s_imag =  0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `s` object is a type of `sympy.core.add.Add` you should use sympy to extract specific parts:

```
>>> sympy.re(s)
16.3617836069885
>>> sympy.im(s)
-0.632549329011278
```

or convert them to a suitable format for the `numpy`

```
>>> np.complex(s)
(16.361783606988478-0.6325493290112776j)
>>> np.real(np.complex(s))
16.361783606988478
>>> np.imag(np.complex(s))
-0.6325493290112776
```

[Convert from sympy.core.add.Add to numpy complex number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545831/convert-from-sympy-core-add-add-to-numpy-complex-number)